# After tns build android --release app doesn't make REST calls

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular

*Releted to [this](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/8188)*

I wrote a cross-platform app with NativeScript + Angular.

I create the .keystore file with this command (as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/publishing/publishing-android-apps#release-certificate)):

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore <my-release-key>.keystore -alias <alias_name> -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000`

I build the release apk with this command:

`tns build android --release --key-store-path "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_201\bin\<name>.keystore" --key-store-password <password> --key-store-alias <alias> --key-store-alias-password <alias-password>`

Then I installed the apk file on my Android devices (Android 9 and Android 8) but when I try to login ( => make a REST call) it does nothing.
Nothing is shown, no errors and no calls made.

I'm using the version 6.2.0 of Nativescript.
I found this problem after migrating the project to NativeScript 6.

Where am I wrong? Did I miss something?

**UPDATE**

I try the second command with `run` instead of `build` but the console doesn't show anything when I press the login button.
The console rimains stuck on this sentence:

> Successfully installed on device with identifier 'xxxxxx'.

**UPDATE**

I deleted the 'hooks', 'node_modules' and 'platforms' folders and then rebuild the app but nothing changed.

**UPDATE**
Here is the code of the button.

The first alert is raised when I press the button with empty email and empty password.

The second alert is raised when I press the button with all the credentials.

The third even the credentials are right is never raised.

*login.component.ts*

```
public login() {
      if(!this.user.email || !this.user.password){
        let options = {
            title: 'ATTENZIONE!',
            message: 'Inserire tutte le credenziali',
            okButtonText: 'OK'
        };

        alert(options);            //first
      } else {
         alert("HELLO WORLD!");    //second
         this.userService.login(this.user).subscribe((res) => {
           alert(res);             //third
           localStorage.setItem("authenticated", true);
           localStorage.setItem("access_token", "bearer " + res.access_token);
           localStorage.setItem("username", this.user.email);
         },
         (err)=>{
           console.log("Something went wrong "+err);
           alert("Credenziali errate");
           return;
         }
         );
       }
      return;
    }
```

*user.service.ts*

```
login(user: User) {
      let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

      urlSearchParams.append('username', user.email);
      urlSearchParams.append('password', user.password);
      urlSearchParams.append('grant_type','password');

      let body = urlSearchParams.toString();

      var url = Config.apiUrl + "/token";

      return this.http.post(url, body , { headers : this.getCommonHeaders() })
      .map(res => res.json())
      .catch( (error: any) => {Observable.throw(error.json().error)} );
}
```

`http` is from `@angular/http`

Comment: are you using an http server ? in that case you need to add a network security config file / allow cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I'm using a https server created with asp.NET

Comment: I update the question. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem changing the http client from `Http` of `@angular/core` (deprecated) to `HttpClient` of `@angular/common/http`.